# How to send email without displaying the hostname of the server in "from" section

Tags: php, email, web

Whenever I send an email to my clients, their inbox shows the email details of my server that is hosting my website, instead of the email I mention in the `from` variable. something like this

```
 From John Smith username704@sadalsuud.hostingService.com
```

What I want is this

```
 From accounts@myWebsite.com
```

Help will be appreiated. I am clueless as to whether it is a question more suitable for mentioning in [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). If so, then let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

What Narek says sometimes works, but kind of depends of the settings. I had a simular problem in the past using mail() and whatever i tried, i sometimes just got the hostname. It appeared to be a server(settings) issue.

What did help me, was using Swiftmailer over SMTP ( http://swiftmailer.org/ ) instead. You should give it a try, it's a very nice script.